# Make a component fill all available space on screen

Tags: android, view

I want something like this:

[image]

But I don't know how to resize the TextView so it gets all the available space on screen which is not ocuppied by the EditText or the Buttons. May I do it in the code, or in the xml?

At XML I tried putting the TextView into a FrameLayout, but it makes no difference. Currently looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/consola"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:scrollbars = "vertical"
            android:text="@string/hello"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/comando"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:text="Conectar"
            android:id="@+id/boton_conectar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:text="Enviar"
            android:id="@+id/boton_enviar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

At the code I'm just checking if the Buttons are pushed with Listeners. One of them, when pushed, gets the text at the EditText, and appends it to the TextView. It works, and TextView gets higher, while EditText and Buttons downs one line. If I go on appending lines, finaly EditText and Buttons get out of the screen. I want to avoid this behaviour, and accomplish to get this 3 widgets sticked to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: What @dmon said, plus you might want to check out [relative layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) to flatten your view hierarchy -- the Android UI builder in Eclipse is getting quite good at guessing how to position things, but also check out the XML attributes that relative layout supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `android:layout_weight=1` attribute, like the buttons on the bottom of the form. That will assign most of the space to it and anything that's left to the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the weight. This should give you what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:text="TextView"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="Button"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp">
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

(Side note: When using weight, setting the corresponding height/width to `0dp` sometimes gets around some weird behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

Try android:fillViewport="true".